# Regex for number which may have comma and/or hyphen.Some valid inputs are: 1 1,4 1-4 1,3-5

Tags: regex

Can some suggest me the answer, I have been trying few, but they are not working.
I tried

`^([0-9],|-)*$`

Comment: please give more information, testing strings, intended output etc and some more info on the regex patterns you have tried would be good

Comment: Yes, please give us some sample input and tell us what the matches would be.

Answer (score 1):

From your question title it seems you will ned this

```
^[0-9]+([,-][0-9]+)*$
```